# How I config zk port for kafka in terraform

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, terraform, terraform-provider-docker

As you know. kafka is depends on zookeeper.
I want to config zk port for kafka.

`zk`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
  }
}

resource "docker_image" "zookeeper" {
  name = "ubuntu/zookeeper:latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "zookeeper" {
  image = docker_image.zookeeper.name
  name  = "zookeeper_test"
  ports {
    internal = 2181
    external = 12181
  }
}
```

`kafka`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
  }
}

resource "docker_image" "kafka" {
  name = "ubuntu/kafka:latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "kafka" {
  image = docker_image.kafka.name
  name  = "kafka_test"
// Maybe this field "command" to use, but it's not work.
  command = [
    "-e", "ZOOKEEPER_PORT=12181"
  ]
  ports {
    internal = 9092
    external = 19092
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [env option](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs/resources/container#env). Additionally, in order to tell terraform that the Kafka container depends on the Zookeeper, you have to use [implicit dependency](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#references-to-resource-attributes) to make sure one is created before the other:

```
resource "docker_container" "kafka" {
  image = docker_image.kafka.name
  name  = "kafka_test"
  env = [
    "ZOOKEEPER_PORT=${docker_container.zookeeper.ports[0].external}"
  ]
  ports {
    internal = 9092
    external = 19092
  }
}
```